# My program returns 0 when passing values into the output function

Tags: c++

I have a code that I wrote where it is supposed to pass the values of the variables through each function and calculate the score using the formulas within each function. When passing through the functions, it passes each variable into the function, but then it doesn't output the correct value. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the way I am trying to pass the scores through the output function, or if it is something completely different. Here's my code that I wrote, and any help is awesome as I am at a basic level class. My function names are supposed to be the same as this is the prompt given by my professor.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double touchdown;
double extraPoint;
double fieldGoal;
double twoPoints;
double score;
double points;
double footballScore(double touchdown, double extraPoint, double points);
double footballScore(double touchdown, double fieldGoal, double extraPoint, double points);
double footballScore(double touchdown, double fieldGoal, double extraPoint, double points, double twoPoints);
double output(double score, double points);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    touchdown=5;
    extraPoint=3;
    fieldGoal=4;
    twoPoints=2;
    footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points);
    footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points,fieldGoal);
    footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points,fieldGoal,twoPoints);
    output(score,score);
    cout<<"The score for the football team is: "<<score<<endl;

    return a.exec();
}

//Function Definitions
double footballScore(double touchdown, double extraPoint, double points)
    {
     points=(touchdown*6)+extraPoint;
     return points;
    }

double footballScore(double touchdown, double fieldGoal, double extraPoint, double points)
    {
     points=(touchdown*6)+extraPoint+(fieldGoal*3);
     return points;
    }

double footballScore(double touchdown, double fieldGoal, double extraPoint, double points, double twoPoints)
    {
     points=(touchdown*6)+extraPoint+(fieldGoal*3)+(twoPoints*2);
     return points;
    }

double output(double score, double points)
    {
     score=points;
     return score;
    }
```

Comment: In `main` you're not using the values returned from the functions. Where exactly do you expect to see any changes?

Comment: Try `score = footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points);` then figure out what is needed to add more scores from the other function calls. Also none of your variables should be global variables.

Answer (score 1):

To get the answer, you need to save the result in a variable, then print it.

```
score = footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points);
cout << "The score using formula 1 is" << score << endl;
score = footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points,fieldGoal);
cout << "The score using formula 2 is" << score << endl;
score = footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points,fieldGoal,twoPoints);
cout << "The score using formula 3 is" << score << endl;
```

The `output` function isn't doing anything.

It would probably be a good idea to read a tutorial on functions. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_functions.asp) is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the returned values.

```cpp
score = footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points);
output(score,score);
score = footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points,fieldGoal);
output(score,score);
score = footballScore(touchdown,extraPoint,points,fieldGoal,twoPoints);
output(score,score);
```

The assignment of `score` in the `output` function does nothing, as the parameter `score` shadows the global `score` variable.